# Removing %20 from URI Relative Path

Tags: c#, uri, relative-path

I am generating a relative path from 1 directory to another. If the OutputDirectoryName property is a directory containing spaces, the spaces are encoded using %20, rather than a space. I am creating a relative path to a windows folder, so I must have my relatiave path using spaces. Is there a clean way to specify how the URI is encoded? I know I could do a stirng replace on the relativePath.ToString(), but am wondering if there's a better implementation.
Thanks.

```
public string GetOutputDirectoryAsRelativePath(string baseDirectory)
{
    Uri baseUri = new Uri(baseDirectory);
    Uri destinationUri = new Uri(OutputDirectoryName);
    Uri relativePath = baseUri.MakeRelativeUri(destinationUri);
    return relativePath.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to replace the %20 with a space ? That is the correct way to represent a space in a URI. If you pass the strings to code that is expecting URIs then it will know that %20 means space.

Comment: @andy: He probably wants a Windows file path, which is not URL-encoded.

Comment: @SLarks, that's correct. @andynormancx, "I am creating a relative path to a windows folder"

Comment: Simply replacing the %20 is definitely not the way to go. There are other valid characters in Windows paths that will be encoded by the Uri class. Using Uri.UnescapeDataString looks like the best bet to me.

Comment: @andy, you are correct. This isn't in the Answers section, so it has to go to Darth. Thank you!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx

Comment: That's the ticket. Although Andy added it as a comment first.

Comment: No, Darth beat me fair and square. I just pointed out why UnescapeDataString is needed rather than just replacing the %20

Answer (score 2):

Use *[HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx)*

Answer (score 2):

```
string sRelativeFilePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(new Uri(sAbsolutePath + "\\", false).MakeRelative(new Uri(filename)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at Server.UrlDecode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

The space character is not the only one that is encoded.

Comment: Server.UrlDecode() is unresolved even after referencing System.Web in my csproj. Odd...