# Convert HTML query to normal string

Tags: c#, html

I have a webmethod and get my queryString with this code:

```
string name = "";
        int pos7 = context.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("name");
        if (pos7 >= 0)
            name = context.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.Substring(pos7 + 5);
```

The problem is the adresse "www.test.com?name=tiki song" will be end up in "tiki%20song" on my string.

How to avoid that?

(Yes I could replace the %20 to " " but there are a lot of more of that kind, right?"

Comment: Have you looked at HttpUtility.HtmlDecode or WebUtility.HtmlDecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Uri.UnescapeDataString

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per this previous you could create a URI and extract it using "UnescapeDataString" ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706555/removing-20-from-uri-relative-path)).  Referencing this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx) page.

Or alternatively, you can use some of the [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods as MikeBarkemeyer had mentioned in the comments.